# ambiguous tag: "duplicate-display"

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just stumbled upon the [duplicate-display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-display), which seems to be quite ambiguous:

- 2 questions use it related to display mirroring
- 2 questions have it referring to detect duplicate files
- 1 question interprets it on "near-identical sources"

Though currently holding no more than 5 questions, this is not what it should be like: a tag should be clear, and not that "wide-spread". While I can see the latter 3 questions somehow belonging into the same area (i.e. duplicate files), display mirroring is definitely something different.

The name `duplicate-display` is much too ambiguous here, as it can be interpreted both ways. Quoting our [help-center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Some possibilities to improve that:

- files: either use `duplicate-files` or `dupe-check` (or something on this way)
- display: if one really wants to *duplicate* it, the correct term would be `diplay-mirroring`. But do we really need a specific tag for that?

Again from our help-center:

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible

We already have the [display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) tag (currently holding 18 questions). Wouldn't that be sufficient here?

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in my question, I suggest we...

1. re-tag the display mirroring questions [display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display)
2. <s>rename the [duplicate-display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-display) tag to something more appropriate, e.g. `duplicate-files`</s>
   As per [Timmy's answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1115/185): Better re-tag those file related questions to [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management), and let the `duplicate-display` die. Optionally, create some synonym to re-route "duplicate" typers to `file-management`.
   <sup>(Edited at vote-count +4)</sup>

thus effectively eliminating the ambiguous [duplicate-display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-display) (the system then should take care of removing it).

Comment: Seems reasonable. Go for it!

Comment: Thanks, @AngeloFuchs! I'll just wait a little for more "voices" – though I'm pretty sure it will be this :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest renaming the [duplicate-display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-display) tag into [display-mirroring](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display-mirroring), and retagging the questions about duplicate files into the existing [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) tag.

While "Display mirroring" does fall under the "display" category, it also includes more aspects, such as networking. On the other hand "duplicate files" does not offer much more information than "file management"

Other examples are these two questions, which deal with duplicate files and are both tagged under [file-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management)

[Software to find duplicate files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/948/6834)

[Copy/paste program that automatically renames duplicate files of different sizes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7185/6834)

Comment: Good points, especially with the `file-management` tag suggestion – as that already exists. But keeping in mind the general rule to "avoid creating new tags if possible": Do you really think those two questions justify a new tag *right now*? We've also got the `multi-monitor` tag which might cover this.

Comment: @Izzy I am not suggesting the creation of a new tag, but simply renaming the `duplicate-display` into a less vague `display-mirroring`. The end result is still one more tag than your edited answer though, so you make a good point. Two questions aren't enough. It makes more sense to re-tag them into `display` + `networking` depending on the contents of each question

Comment: Full ack to that. And after all, we can create `display-mirroring` anytime later if we feel it necessary. // Can I conclude then you agree with the *edited* variant of my answer (which is rather a merge of our "original" answers)?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I agree with your edited answer, +1. The `networking` tag might also be needed for the re-tagging in your first point since usually display mirroring occurs over a network connection.

Comment: We already have a `networking` tag, so that's not an issue :) But "networking" is not the primary idea behind those questions, though you're correct it's mostly related – so I wouldn't force it upon them unless it's explicitely required.